# why regexp doesn't match?

Tags: php, regex

Below is a pattern that matches numbers. It works almost. The second line should be matched with `99` but there is no match? Why?

```
(?<!\d[- ]|[\d.,])\(?-?(?:(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:[. ]\d{3})*|\d*))|0)(?:\b|[,]\d{1,3})-?\)?(?![\d.,\/]|-[\d\/])


100,00stk => 100,00
99stk => 99 \\ this is not matched
10,45stk => 10,45
```

https://regex101.com/r/nwRCKo/1

Comment: It is due to the word boundary in `(?:\b|,\d{1,3})`, see https://regex101.com/r/nwRCKo/2, if you remove it you will get a match. However, the pattern is too vague and probably won't work even after this fix.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew after I remove `\b|´ it still doesn't work

Comment: It does - https://regex101.com/r/nwRCKo/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew create an answer :)

Comment: Ok, but `(?![\d.,\/]|-[\d\/])` does not work for you the way you need I believe. At least after removing `\b` it will stop working in many cases. The pattern should be fixed, but I have no requirements for it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the requirements is more or less as it is. The number must not be followed by a new number `(?![\d.,\/]|-[\d\/])`

Comment: Yeah, so the match should not be returned at all, right?

Comment: no, if the nuber is followed by a new number (except if there is a space)

Comment: Ok, please see solution below, and once you have trouble with this pattern please add a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the use of word boundary, but fixing the issue is not that evident.

The main point about the regex you have is that it matches some numbers in some specific context, and the lookarounds on both sides are meant to fail the match, so that you do not get a match at all. If you place a negative lookahead after an optional `)` char, the regex engine may backtrack and you will still get this match. You need to prevent any backtracking here after removing the word boundary.

So, replace `(?:\b|[,]\d{1,3})` with `(?:[,]\d{1,3})?` and make all the subsequent optional patterns atomic by applying the possessive quantifiers:

```php
(?<!\d[- ]|[\d.,])\(?-?(?:(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:[. ]\d{3})*|\d*))|0)(?:,\d{1,3})?+-?+\)?+(?![\d.,\/]|-[\d\/])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nwRCKo/3).

Comment: The last `?+` before the negative lookahead. Is the `+` needed? The `)` before is actually not a group but an actual `)` because there is an escape char in front of it

Comment: In the beginning of the pattern just after the negative lookbehind there are two optional chars `\(?-?`. Should they also have the `+`?

Comment: @clarkk That is not usually necessary. The lookbehind restriction is probably fine to backtrack, you want to fail any match if there is a digit, a `.`, a `,` or a digit with space/`-`. `?+` is fine in PCRE, it means "match optionally a single occurrence and never give back". So, if `\)?+` matches a `)` char, it will never be re-tried.